# Can we set web view height and width in android

Tags: android-webview

can we set webview height and width in static for android?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0):

yes you can set height and width for web view.set in XML file 
Here's code snippet 
(
WebView
                    android:id="@+id/webView1"
                    android:layout_width="250dip"
                    android:layout_height="250dip"
                   /)

Answer (score 0):

AFTER you done that, the dynamic content size becomes important:
You need will need the width and height of the WebView **CONTENTS**, **after** you loaded your HTML to do uselful things.
YES you do, but there is no getContentWidth method (only a view port value),
AND the getContentHeight() is inaccurate !

Answer: sub-class WebView:

```
/*
  Jon Goodwin
*/
package com.example.html2pdf;//your package

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.webkit.WebView;

class CustomWebView extends WebView
{
    public int rawContentWidth   = 0;                         //unneeded
    public int rawContentHeight  = 0;                         //unneeded
    Context    mContext          = null;                      //unneeded

    public CustomWebView(Context context)                     //unused constructor
    {
        super(context);
        mContext = this.getContext();
    }   

    public CustomWebView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) //inflate constructor
    {
        super(context,attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }

    public int getContentWidth()
    {
        int ret = super.computeHorizontalScrollRange();//working after load of page
        rawContentWidth = ret;
        return ret;
    }

    public int getContentHeight()
    {
        int ret = super.computeVerticalScrollRange(); //working after load of page
        rawContentHeight = ret;
        return ret;
    }
//=========
}//class
//=========
```